# Error during incremental deploy: java.io.IOException:

Tags: java, jsp, wildfly

Estoy realizando un login con servidor wildfly, al primer inicio me arranco bien sin ningún problema mas o menos a la tercera ejecución me empezó a salir este error, desde que funciono hasta que dejo de funcionar solo cambie que limpiara los setter despues de validar un usuario nada mas y emepezo a salir ese error que puede ser ?? wildfly 20.0.1 final

```
Error during incremental deploy: java.io.IOException: C:/WildFly/standalone/deployments/Login.war
C:\Users\andrea\Downloads\Login\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1039: Deployment error: Error during incremental deploy: java.io.IOException: C:/WildFly/standalone/deployments/WooClic.war
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Qué errores tienes en el log?

Comment: Lo único que me sale de error es lo que puse en la informacion si voy a la linea del link me muestra esto ```    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>  ``` elimine el servidor volvi agregarlo y sirvio pero mas o menos en la tercera ejecucion vuelve y muestra el error de Error during incremental deploy, limpio y contruyo el proyecto y sirve pero de nuevo a la tercera o a reiniciar el servidor sigue el mismo error

Comment: Si haces un `clean` y `build` te da lo mismo?

Comment: Si ya lo hice y vuelve a funcionar pero a la tercera ejecución vuelve al mismo error.

Comment: Que hay en netbeans log files ?